# Selecting the label on a text input but posting the value without changing the text value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to be able to use autocomplete to search through a list of labels, then post the value.  This is done successfully.  The problem is when the label is selected it changes to the value.  So the user selects an autocompleted value say burger but on selection, it changes to the id say 18.  On the post, it actually sends the right info which is the id.  It's just maybe confusing to people when they see a number instead of a value when selected.  First time using jquery so forgive me if its something simple.

database extraction get_meals.php:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$return_arr[] = array('value'=>$row['food_id'], 'label' => $row['food']);
}
```

Here is the jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
   $(".auto").autocomplete({
       source: "get_meals.php",
       minLength: 0
   });
   });
   </script>
```

tried stuff like:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);

    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.

select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#searchval').val(ui.item.value);
    return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
    },


 focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="food_id" name="food_id" value="" class='auto'>
<input type='text' id="food" name='food' value="" class='auto'>
```

Then the following to autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "add_meals_frm_.php",
            minLength: 0,

            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#food_id').val(ui.item.value);
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#food").val(ui.item.label);
            }


       });
    });
</script>
```